# Install sage script using setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, sage

I am trying to build an installer for a sage script using setuptools.  Here is what I have.

My `setup.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from setuptools import setup

__name__ = 'sage-test'
__version__ = '0.0'

setup(name=__name__,
      scripts=['sage-test'],
)
```

The `sage-test` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sage

from sage.all import GF

print(GF(5))
```

I now do `./setup.py build` and `./setup.py install`.  When I try to run sage-test, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/sage-test", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('sage-test==0.0.0', 'sage-test')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 517, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1443, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage_test-0.0.0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/sage-test", line 3, in <module>
    __requires__ = 'sage-test==0.0.0'
ImportError: No module named sage.all
```

Any ideas how to get this to work?  (Note that I can run `./sage-test` within the current directory and everything works.)

Answer (score 0):

This may not help, but this looks suspicious.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/
```

Maybe you need to do everything within `sage -sh` - I wouldn't be surprised if there was some env var that was not set up properly.  I don't know exactly why but maybe it's picking up your system Python somehow.